# How to disable bootstrap duallistbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make bootstrap duallistbox for read only, Does anyone know how to do it?

here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     $('.test2').bootstrapDualListbox({
      nonSelectedListLabel: 'Non-selected',
      selectedListLabel: 'Selected',
      preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
      moveOnSelect: false,
      /*nonSelectedFilter: 'ion ([7-9]|[1][0-2])'*/
    });

 });

<c:forEach items="${item1}" var="tm" varStatus="status">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="item${status.index}">${tm.value.name}</label>
        <div class="displayShowCase">
         <c:choose>
                <form:select path="itemMap['${tm.key}']" id="item${status.index}" class="test2" multiple="multiple">
                        <form:options items="${tm.value.displayList}"/>
                </form:select>                                  
      </c:choose>
   </div>
 </div></c:forEach>
```

I already checked on some websites, but could not find any solution, 
if you can give me some suggestion , that would be great!

thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(".bootstrap-duallistbox-container").find("*").prop("disabled", true);
```